# Crystal Report 11 and C# 2005 Export to PDF issue (Rendering issue, random pages)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2005, crystal-reports, export-to-pdf

I'm working on rewriting a vb6 application in .NET that exports our Crystal Reports to Pdfs on a daily basis. I'm running into an issue when I export to PDF, the report renders properly (2 pages) in a Crystal Report Viewer, but when I export it (either through the viewer or programatically, it turns into a 11 page document, when it should be a 2 page document).  I'm not sure if this is something with the report, or if this is something with the Export()... Please help!

Comment: What is on the other 9 pages? Are they blank?

Comment: Figured it out, I went into the Report Explorer and noticed there were a ton of extra fields in the details section that were not actually showing up in the viewer.  I removed the extra fields and voila, back to two pages.

Answer (score 0):

*[The text of this answer was originally written by [Eric](https://stackoverflow.com/users/229776/eric)]*

Figured it out, I went into the Report Explorer and noticed there were a ton of extra fields in the details section that were not actually showing up in the viewer. I removed the extra fields and voila, back to two pages